# Pyodbc execute sqlserver stored procedure -- how to pass in DEFAULT parameter for User Defined Table

Tags: python, sql-server, stored-procedures, pyodbc

I have the following User Defined Table, as you can see I have 2 columns have DEFAULT values:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.mytable AS TABLE(
[MYID] BIGINT,
[MYVALUE] INT,

[CURRENT_INDEX] BIT default 1,
[CURRENT_TS] DATETIME2(7) default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

)

Here is my dummy Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MY_PROCEDURE  @temp_table dbo.mytable READONLY
    AS
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO dbo.main_table
        (MYID,MYVALUE,CURRENT_INDEX,CURRENT_TS)
        SELECT * FROM @temp_table as tt
    END
    GO
```

And I'm trying to execute this stored procedure by passing in the user defined table from Python using pyodbc. As you can see, I'm trying to pass in only `MYID` and `MYVALUE` to the stored procedure and I expect the user defined table to auto-fill the default values without passing in.

```
def _insert_stored_procedure(cursor, table_val_parameter: list):
    """
    Call the stored procedure for table insert/update
    """
    cursor.execute("{CALL MY_PROCEDURE (?)}",
                   (table_val_parameter,))
    cursor.commit()



conn = DBCONN_Singleton(connection_type)
cursor = conn.cursor
_tvp = [[1,100],[2,150],[3,200]]
_insert_update_stored_procedure(cursor, _tvp)
```

Clearly the above failed with the following error:

```
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Trying to pass a table-valued parameter with 2 column(s) where the corresponding user-defined table type requires 4 column(s). (500) (SQLParamData)')
```

So my questions are:

1. Given the above scenario, how can I pass in only `MYID` and `MYVALUE` to let the store procedure or user defined table to auto-fill the missing values with the DEFAULT
2. If not, how can I pass the default values from python, for example, I want to do something like:

   `_tvp = [[1,100,DEFAULT,DEFAULT],[2,150,DEFAULT,DEFAULT],[3,200,DEFAULT,DEFAULT]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there is currently no mechanism – e.g., something like `pyodbc.DEFAULT` – to represent a literal `DEFAULT` as would be used stored procedure calls. This workaround is a bit clunky but it seems to do the job:

```py
cnxn.autocommit = True
crsr = cnxn.cursor()
crsr.fast_executemany = True

# (remove previous test data)
crsr.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.main_table")

data = ([1 ,100], [2, 150],[3, 200])
crsr.execute("CREATE TABLE #temp (MYID bigint, MYVALUE int)")
crsr.executemany("INSERT INTO #temp (MYID, MYVALUE) VALUES (?, ?)", data)
sql = """\
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @tvp dbo.mytable;
INSERT INTO @tvp (MYID, MYVALUE) SELECT MYID, MYVALUE FROM #temp
EXEC dbo.MY_PROCEDURE @tvp
"""
crsr.execute(sql)

pprint(crsr.execute("SELECT * FROM dbo.main_table").fetchall())
"""console output:
[(1, 100, True, datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 22, 12, 17, 14, 623333)),
 (2, 150, True, datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 22, 12, 17, 14, 623333)),
 (3, 200, True, datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 22, 12, 17, 14, 623333))]
"""
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides @Gord Thompson's answer, I also found another approach and it's actually pretty simple:

First, drop the defaults from the user-defined table type:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.mytable AS TABLE(
[MYID] BIGINT,
[MYVALUE] INT)
```

Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MY_PROCEDURE  @temp_table dbo.mytable READONLY
    AS
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO dbo.main_table
            (MYID,MYVALUE,CURRENT_INDEX,CURRENT_TS)
            SELECT *,1,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP FROM @temp_table as tt
END
GO
```